# Identify this tree growing at Stellenbosch University

Tags: identification

This woody shrub or tree is growing under the assegaais by the Neelsie at the University of Stellenbosh in South Africa. What species is it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: How big is it (height and spread)? Does it have a single, main trunk, or is it actually more of a large shrub?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks like *Rhaphiolepis*, a genus of mostly shrubs in the family Rosaceae. The two most widely cultivated species are *R. umbellata* and *R. indica*. These species are quite similar and easily confused. According to: http://keybase.rbg.vic.gov.au/keys/show/6559 they can be separated by the following characters.

Leaves serrate ------------------> R. indica 
Leaves entire or crenate ---> R. umbellata

Thanks to the good close up images provided, I think we can be fairly sure the specimen in question is *Rhaphiolepis umbellata*, as the leaves shown clearly have margins which are entire (smooth) to crenate (notched/ scalloped/ with rounded teeth) as opposed to serrate (sharp, saw like teeth).

Some links for further info:

https://keyserver.lucidcentral.org/weeds/data/media/Html/rhaphiolepis_umbellata.htm

https://www.rhs.org.uk/Plants/14464/i-Rhaphiolepis-umbellata-i/Details

http://www.missouribotanicalgarden.org/PlantFinder/PlantFinderDetails.aspx?taxonid=290648&isprofile=0&